# My function is not running and I don't know why? (Angular 8) I get no errors

Tags: angular, typescript

I have below function:

```
Join(movementId: string, movement: Movement, userId: string) {
  let fetchedUserId: string;
  let userList = [];
  fetchedUserId = userId;
  userList = movement.userList;
  userList.push(fetchedUserId);
  movement.userList = userList;
  console.log('kkk');
  console.log(movement);
  return this.auth.token.pipe(
    take(1),
    switchMap(token => {
      console.log('kk');
      return this.http.put(
        `https://gridt-85476.firebaseio.com/movements/${movementId}.json?auth=${token}`,
        { ...movement, userList, id: null }
      );
    })
  );
}
```

I am a beginner in Angular and trying to make a small app. I will not explain the app right now since it's not needed. This function is supposed to add to the list of users when you join a thing in the app. The problem is after pipe it just stops working and I don't know why. I checked and all the information that the function needs and it receives it correctly. I get no errors no warning nothing. I am honestly stuck. Here is the full code https://github.com/GridtNetwork/gridt-client/tree/Andra/gridt/src Please help

Answer (score 0):

In `RxJS` calling `Join()` won't make the observable sequence take flight. You have to do `Join().subscribe(data => console.log(data))`. Are you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

also your function returns an observable, i guess you should provide appropriate return type to it, like

`Join(movementId: string, movement:Movement, userId: string): observabel<any>`